# Chrome can't open a profile using selenium python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

When I run this code

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
chrome_options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
chrome_options.add_argument(r"user-data-dir=C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Profile 1")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Users\micha\Desktop\Visual_projects\chromedriver.exe', chrome_options = chrome_options)

driver.get("https://store.steampowered.com/")
This error pops up : [12216:1336:0411/232857.718:ERROR:browser_switcher_service.cc(238)] XXX Init()
```

Could someone please help me. I don't know what is wrong but the programm won't open the new profile I created. Any help would be appreciated.

I searched everywhere how to fix this error but I think the guides are outdated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing to check would be, if your ChromeDriver-Executable matches the version of the Chrome you have installed (under Help/About Google Chrome in your browser). There are versions 79, 80 and 81 mostly in use. You can find the current ChromeDrivers for all three versions here: https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads.

Answer (score 1):

Check your [Chrome browser version](https://www.howtogeek.com/299243/which-version-of-chrome-do-i-have/) and your Chrome [webdriver](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/) version. If both are same then issue should be solved.